# Excel extract vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making an Excel extract and have a question about some of the formatting. So basically what I'm doing is going into SQL SERVER and selecting a bunch of data. Then I'm writing it to Excel (in VB6 application).

```
xlrow=6
xlcol=1
While Not g_RS3.EOF
    For i = 0 To RCOUNT - 1
        Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("School")
        xlCol = xlCol + 1
        Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("LastName") & " ," &  g_RS3("FirstName")
        xlCol = xlCol + 1
        Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("Q01")
        xlCol = xlCol + 1
        Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("Q02")
        xlCol = xlCol + 1
        Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("Q03")
        xlCol = xlCol + 1
        Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("q04")
        xlCol = xlCol + 1
        Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS3("q05")
        xlcol=1
        xlrow=xlrow+1
    next i
wend
```

So I write this data to Excel and everything works great. But I'm having a hard time with formatting.

I'd like to make the font = 9 and put borders all around the cell. Because this is dynamic (I don't know how many records there will be, I'm trying to format it as it gets written). I tried putting this line after every time I do `xlcol=xlcol+1`, so I was doing something like:

```
xlcol=xlcol+1
cells(xlrow, xlcol).font.size=9
```

But I have to do this after every line, also with borders. Is there a shorter way to do it??? Thanks!

EDIT: Including this code does not do the job for me, it only gives me borders on left and right and not top and bottom because it goes by the entire range. Also it only changes the font in the first column ...."SCHOOL"

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(xlRow, xlCol))
rng.Font.Size = 9
rng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
rng.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
rng.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
rng.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

I need to have something that will write the borders after each line of data

Comment: Why can't you format after all the data is written?

Comment: because it's dynamic, i dont knwo how long the recordset is, therefore I don't know how to specify my range

Comment: That's why you wait until it's done. Then you know what the range is. Edit: am I missing something?

Comment: You know where it starts, yes?  So can't you just get the end cell and select the entire range and format it?

Comment: Just use `UsedRange` once its done

Comment: it's an extract to excel - for the application users - it's not a report for me, I want it set up so when users generate it on their end - it's properly formatted

Comment: Use start row and start row + recordcount to select a range and do what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not something like this after your loop:

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(Cells(6,1), Cells(xlrow, xlcol))

rng.font.size = 9
rng.Borders.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
rng.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
etc...
```

Comment: i still would have to loop, wouldn't i? just setting xlrow, and xlcol will not go through all the rows to format it

Comment: Yes, this would go after your loop.  That way the xlrow and xlcol values should correspond to the last cell handled by the loop which gives us the end of your range.

Comment: If I user your provided code I get borders on every cell.  The top row does not show the border very well but if you cut the cell and paste it to another cell you can see that there is in fact a border around it.  You can adjust the sizes to be bigger if you want them to be more noticeable.  Also you can use `rng.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous` if you want to have each border the same in the range.

Comment: I am to include your code after my loop ends? I used the code that i provided in edit. Only the first column of data (SCHOOL) was font 9 and I got borders on the right side of the SCHOOL name. No where else. I think I might have to include a loop around the code you put in the answer. Not sure. I'm not that great with VBA sorry :(

Comment: I think I see the issue.  It looks like your xlcol is set to 1 at the end of each iteration of the loop.  You will need another way to track the last column value so that after your loop you will have the correct column value.

Comment: so i got it to work i did set rng = range(Cells(6,1), cells(xlrow, 15)) ---- i have 15 columns. However, i only get the border at the end of row 15. WHYY?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112529/discussion-between-zack-lore-and-fatboyslim7).